# Usually disconnect during sending imagedata through socket.io

Tags: react-native, socket.io

I am using socket.io to transmit an image, which is base64 encoded, from a react-native mobile to a server. But disconnect occur frequently (70% failure).

Such situation won't happen while sending text. Here is my code simplified:

Server Side:

```
const app = require('http').createServer();
app.listen(3005);
const server = require('socket.io')(app);
server.on('connection', client => {
    client.on('data', data => console.log(data));
});
```

Client Side:

```
import io from "socket.io-client";
const socket = io("ws://the_lan_ip_of_server:3005");
socket.on("connect", () => console.log("Connect", socket.id));
socket.on("disconnect", () => console.log("Disconnect));

// I just copy the file obtained from console.
let file = {
    height: 1802,
    width: 1080,
    type: null,
    fileName: 'Capture+_2018-07-06-12-05-12.png',
    fileSize: 2659778,
    path: '/storage/emulated/0/Capture+/Capture+_2018-07-06-12-05-12.png',
    data: 'the image data',
    uri: 'content://media/external/images/media/483',
    isVertical: true,
    originalRotation: 0
};
let data = { type: "File", "action": "Create", base64: file.data };
console.log(data.type, data.action, socket.id);
socket.emit("data", data);
```

No console log obtained from Server Side, But for ClientSide Log is

```
07-06 17:49:09.400: I/ReactNativeJS(22397): 'Connect', 'JnghiSpOSpufU85tAAAF'
07-06 17:49:09.421: I/ReactNativeJS(22397): 'Submit', 'File', 'Create', 'JnghiSpOSpufU85tAAAF'
07-06 17:49:14.445: I/ReactNativeJS(22397): Disconnect
07-06 17:49:18.363: I/ReactNativeJS(22397): 'Connect', 'CbqHvecSXdmG811KAAAG'
```

Can someone give me some idea to figure out the problem?

Comment: Are you sure there's no error on server side?

Comment: thx,  i miss the error handler on the server side

Comment: no error from server side  :(